# How to know which user is related to an App Store Server Notification?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect, in-app-subscription

I have an in-app subscription, and I've built a notification server and put its url into App Store Connect.

The fields in [the response of App Store Server Notifacation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/responsebody) is too complex to understand. Even I can not find a way to match existing receipts in my system to the newly sent notifications. I don't know any of the notifications marks which user in my app.

Anyone knows about that?

---

I only saved the `transactionIdentifier` feild in every purchase.

Comment: You can look in the unified receipt to find the matching transaction to identify the user

Answer (score 0):

You can categorized notification of each users through using original_transaction_id (which is available in responseBody.Latest_receipt_info)

Answer (score 0):

Try use appAccountToken(UUID). You can set your user ID to custom appAccountToken then App Store will send you transaction payload with your appAccountToken. See here
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product/purchaseoption/3749440-appaccounttoken